# Making a multi-colored candy material in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

If someone knows a good shader setup for pez candy in cycles I would be happy if he/she would share it with me. Here is a reference image:

Ps: I dont want just multi-colored Candy i want to have that grain and the overall look that Pez Candy has.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This seems to be exactly the kind of place where you might want to use the *Random* output of the object info node:

[image]

This output gives a random value between 1 and 0 which is unique to each object. By using a color ramp node, you can use this random value to give each object a color from a defined set of colors:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Where does the intuition that voronoi and noise needs to be multiplied (and inverted) come from? ColorRamp fed by random is also clever.

Comment: @stacker I wanted to use both, and multiplying is sort of my "default" way of combining things.. (I didn't really go into a lot of detail with the texture) As for inverting, I wanted the dots to be more saturated, rather than the space between the dots. I mostly just figured out that it needs to be inverted by plugging things in and looking at the result. :P

Answer (score 1):

Not very convincing, but as a starting point something like this could work:

[image]

[image]

[Demo .blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/32197)

Comment: Maybe also add a some noise and plug it to displacement to get a rougher texture.

Comment: @cegaton yes I also tried a 'multiplier node' value:.3 between 'noise fac' and 'material output displacement'.

Comment: Also the noise should probably transform it is stretched along the longer side. I tried subsurf without success. I can't wait to see @gandalf3 solution.